# How to set up DNS when connecting to two networks?

Tags: centos, dns

I have a linux machine with two network interfaces.  They are both connected to local networks -- one is `192.168.*.*`, the other is `10.*.*.*`.

The `192.168.*.*` network is completely private and does not have internet access.  The `10.*.*.*` network does have internet access.

Currently, I can do external `ping`'s and the names will resolve

```
ping google.com
```

However, when I try to ping a machine name on the `192.168.*.*` network, the name will not resolve

```
ping computer-name
ping computer-name.domain
ping computer-name.domain.local
```

If I specify an IP address, it will resolve

```
ping 192.168.x.x
```

How can I set up DNS settings so that the machine names on the private local network will resolve, but I can still resolve external addresses?

I am using Centos6.

Comment: You'll need to setup a DNS server (e.g. `dnsmasq`) which may be fairly involved or kluge things together in the 1970s style with `/etc/hosts` entries.

Comment: @thrig Both networks have DNS servers.  The problem is that the `192.168.*.*` DNS server obviously can't resolve external addresses.  Is there a way to point to multiple DNS servers?  Or to somehow direct certain requests (like all `domain.local` lookups) to a certain DNS?

Comment: @BrendanAbel, ignoring the networks, does the private DNS on 192.168 cover its own domain?  You're not trying to merge items from two different servers into a single domain of "company.com" or such, are you?

Comment: @BowlOfRed No, there is no merging.  `192.168.*.*` has it's own domain

Comment: Then @thrigs comment is appropriate.  You run your own server.  You direct queries from the domains and networks covered to the servers responsible for them.  The standard unix client resolver can't handle doing this all by itself.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Does that mean I need to set up a local DNS server on this machine, or are you saying I can do the split based on domain name in the `resolv.conf` (is that what you meant by standard resolver?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local resolver libraries assume that any nameserver can resolve all names.  In your case, you can get the side effect that if your local one isn't authoritative, it won't respond.  Then your libraries will retry (after a delay) with the next nameserver.

Better would be to run a local nameserver that will send the data to the correct location quickly.  If you install `dnsmasq`, the meat of the config is pretty simple.  Something like:

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
# This sets up your private domain
server=/privatedomain/192.168.10.15
server=/.168.192.in-addr.arpa/192.168.10.15
```

You don't even have to mention the main server (10.10.1.15) if it's listed as a nameserver in your `resolv.conf`.  If it gets a request for privatedomain, it goes to the local server.  If it gets a request for anything else, it uses the non-localhost servers in resolv.conf.

Then just set up your server as the first one in resolv.conf.

resolv.conf

```
search privatedomain
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.10.1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by modifying my `/etc/resolv.conf` file

```
domain privatedomain
search privatedomain publicdomain.com
nameserver 192.168.10.15
nameserver 10.10.1.15
```

The `privatedomain` is the local `192.168.*.*` network domain name.  The `publicdomain.com` is the domain name for the `10.*.*.*` network with internet access.

It can now resolve all these requests correctly

```
ping computer.privatedomain
ping computer
ping computer2.publicdomain.com
ping google.com
```

The only downside to this is that when I try to resolve a name that isn't reachable from the private domain, there is a noticeable delay.  For example:

```
ping google.com
```

I imagine it's because it's first attempting to resolve the name via the first nameserver on the `privatedomain`, which will eventually timeout, and then goes to the second nameserver which is able to resolve it.

Comment: ... which is why the other answer is better.  It doesn't state it explicitly, and explains things in terms of `dnsmasq`, but what it is indirectly telling you to do is to set up _split horizon DNS service_ with queries for the private part of the DNS namespace forwarded to one resolving proxy DNS server (192.168.10.15) and queries for the rest of the DNS namespace forwarded to another resolving proxy DNS server (10.1.1.15).  `/etc/resolv.conf` alone does not achieve this.  A proxy DNS server (e.g. `dnscache`, `dnsmasq`) configured with a split in the DNS namespace, does.